# Show IDs where two conditions in the same column satisfy

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table1

```
ID    || Basket  || Balls
--------------------------
1     || Ram   || 1  
1     || Rom   || 3  
2     || Ram   || 2  
3     || Rom   || 5
```

Query  - Select all the IDs that have both at least 1 ball in both Ram **and** Rom.

----All the IDs that have at least 1 ball in Ram

```
 SELECT distinct  ID
 INTO #RAM
 FROM Table1
 where balls > =1 and basket = 'Ram'
```

----All the IDs that have at least 1 ball in Rom

```
 SELECT distinct  ID
 INTO #ROM
 FROM Table1
 where balls > =1 and basket = 'Rom'
```

---All the IDs that have both

```
 Select distinct ID 
 INTO #FinalTable
 from #RAM a join #ROM b on a.id = b.id
```

This is what I have written so far it works but I feel there is definitely a more efficient way to do this.

Please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Your syntax suggests that you are using SQL Server, not MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a single aggregation:

```
select id
from table1 t1
group by id
having sum(case when basket = 'Ram' then balls end) > 0 and
       sum(case when basket = 'Rom' then balls end) > 0;
```

Assuming the value of `balls` is never negative or zero, then you only need to check that that the rows exist.  That is a little simpler in *MySQL*:

```
select id
from table1 t1
group by id
having sum(basket = 'Ram') > 0 and
       sum(basket = 'Rom') > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subqueries` to achieve this.

> 1. join RAM
> 2. join ROM
> 3. select count() >= 1

```
select t1.ID
from Table1 t1
join
    (select ID, count(1) ct from Table1 where Basket = 'Ram'
    group by ID) as ram on ram.ID = t1.ID
join
    (select ID, count(1) ct from Table1 where Basket = 'Rom'
    group by ID) as rom as rom.ID = t1.ID
where ram.ct >= 1 and rom.ct >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need Only t use this query and combine your Queries

```
SELECT 
  a.ID 
FROM (SELECT ID FROM Table1 Where Balls >= 1 And Basket = 'RAM') a
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID FROM Table1 Where Balls >= 1 And Basket = 'ROM') b 
ON a.ID = b.ID
```

It only return the OD that are have nmore than 1 ball and are in RoM and RAM

Answer (score 0):

We can group by based on ID,Basket and select records having count greater than 1

```
select distinct a.id from 
(
    select id,basket,count(balls) as cn
    from table1 
    group by id,basket
    having cn>1
) a ;
```